# How would I take imported file and format it to account for spacing?

Tags: paragraphs, verbatim, external-files, input

Basically what I'm trying to do is use something like

```
\input{details.txt}
```

which contains:

> ____Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use   this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur.
>
> ____Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format
> it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur. Here are some random details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex will use this properly and format it. If not... Problems occur.   etc..

*underscores are actual spaces to in included.

I'd like it to looking something like:
[image: Paragraphs]

I feel like this is a pretty trivial problem, but I can't seem to come up with an answer. Verbatim was the closest I came in regards to getting the spaces, but then I have a word wrap issue. Currently I'm working on an unrelated section, and the text is just inputted with the code at the top. Which isn't bad, but there's no tabs nor space between the paragraphs.

Comment: you can set this length with `\parindent`

Comment: @jfbu Actually, I prefer everything to be as is from the file so that a person could tab where they thought they needed and the program would copy it over. Line breaks and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your indentation length by typing this in your preamble (if you want to affect the whole document):

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
```

Where `1em` is the length you want to take into account.  It could also be something like 3mm or any other length you feel is right.

E.g.:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % Just to show you the text block

\begin{document}

\noindent Line zero to show no indentation.

First line with default indentation.

\setlength{\parindent}{15mm}Second line a little more indented.

\setlength{\parindent}{25mm} Why not going to extreme?

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was a lot simpler than I thought. I tried it out and it worked on my \input(file.txt). But what about the extra space between paragraphs?

Comment: @mhag That you can also adjust with `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}`, where `1em` is an arbitrary length of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{details.txt}
                Here are some random details [   ] with stuff everywhere. This
                is
                to
                see
                if
                latex
will use this properly and format it obeying spaces such as [   ] but not
necessarily linebreaks. If not...     Problems occur.     Here are some random
details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex 
will use this properly and format it obeying spaces such as [   ] but not
necessarily linebreaks. If not...     Problems occur.     Here are some random
details with stuff everywhere. This is to see if latex 
will use this properly and format it obeying spaces such as [       ] but not
necessarily linebreaks. If not... (            ) Problems occur. 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter\@vobeyspaces\makeatother
\noindent\input{details.txt}

\makeatletter\def {\hspace{0.2pt\@plus0.1pt\@minus0.1pt}$\cdot$}\makeatother%
\noindent\input{details.txt}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: input file obey spaces]

Comment: the second input shows the end of lines acting as standard spaces (after `is`, `to`, `see`, ... or between `not` and `necessarily` near the end)

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for; thanks. But I misread about the line breaks. What can I do to have those be included?